# Filtering and sorting objects by min price and max price

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-views

I have described the product model as follows: **models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
category = TreeManyToManyField(ProductCategory, blank=True, symmetrical=False, related_name='products',
                               verbose_name='Категория->Подкатегория')
name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True, verbose_name='Наименование товара')
price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, verbose_name='Цена')
```

In **views.py**:

```
def product_list(request, category_slug=None):
category = None
categories = ProductCategory.objects.filter(available=True, is_active=True)
object_list = Product.objects.filter(available=True, is_active=True)
if category_slug:
    category = get_object_or_404(ProductCategory, slug=category_slug)
    object_list = object_list.filter(category=category)
paginator = Paginator(object_list, 16)
page = request.GET.get('page')
try:
    products = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    products = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    products = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
return render(request, 'shop/products/list_by_category/product_list.html', {'category': category,
                                                                            'categories': categories,
                                                                            'products': products,
                                                                            })
```

The problem is that I want to sort the products by the lowest price or the highest price (that is, displaying goods in *min_price* order of price and *max_price* price).
In the template I have a sort form:

```
<div class="secand_fillter">
    <h4>sort by price:</h4>
    <select class="selectpicker">
        <option>descending price</option>
        <option>ascending price</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

As far as I understand correctly, it is necessary to send the parameter by which the goods will be sorted using the GET method, and in the view, by overriding the get_queryset method (receiving the sorting parameter), return the list of products back.

Answer (score 1):

**Ascending**

```
object_list = Product.objects.filter(available=True, is_active=True).order_by('price')
```

**Descending**

```
object_list = Product.objects.filter(available=True, is_active=True).order_by('-price')
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But I probably phrased the question badly. I will try to correct myself.
- At the template level, I have a form in which there are two sort buttons: "price descending" and "price ascending".